# If/else/unless which to choose Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I didnt think I would need to ask this but here goes. I have a app which allows you to check out , check in and set reminders on books for example, this is done by clicking a check_box. So if User1 for example checks out Book1 then that user will only be able to see the check in button when viewing. And then if the same user checks that book in then the check out button will reappear

Then comes user2, they view the same book and in theory should not be able to see any buttons apart from the remind me button (this sends email when book checked back in) by user1.

However with current setup user2 still sees the checkout button, but it is already ticked to say true, which is correct in terms of status but i dont want that button shown.

This is what i have so far (logic for the remind me button doesnt render anything)

```
<% unless current_user.id == @book.user_id   %> 
<%= render 'shared/checkout' %>
<% end %>

<% if current_user.id == @book.user_id %>
<%= render 'shared/checkin' %>
<% end %>

<% if @book.user_id != nil && current_user.id != @book.user_id %>
<% render 'shared/registerinterest' %>
<% end %>
```

Also when a user checks back in a book  this is what i pass to the model, I was thinking the nil value may be causing an issue?

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>

<%= f.label :checked_out, "Check Book Back In" %>
<%= f.check_box :checked_out, {checked: false}, false  %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => nil %>
<%= f.submit 'Check In' %>
<% end %>
```

Cant seem to get my head around this scenario so if someone could and explain why then that would be great as I can learn from it

Thank You

EDIT

im trying this for the register button now based on the anser

```
<% if @book.checked_out == true && current_user.id != @book.user_id %>
<% render 'shared/registerinterest' %>
<% end %>
```

however this is not working?

Comment: so its not just me then? 42 views and no answer or comments (apart from this one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

the code 
`<% unless current_user.id == @book.user_id %>`

is the same as:
`<% if current_user.id != @book.user_id %>`

So, since the user2 id's is 2 it will indeed be differente than the user' id's ( that is 1 ),
and it will display the checkout partial.

My sugestion would be adding to your database a boolean field that informs if the book has been checked out,

```
<% if current_user.id == @book.user_id %>
   <%= render 'shared/checkin' %>
<% elsif @book.checked_out == false %>
   <%= render 'shared/checkout' %>
<% else %>
    #If it goes into this branch of the if/elsif/else, it means that
    # current_user.id != @book.user_id and checked_out == true
    <%= render 'shared/registerinterest' %>
<% end %>
```

And then you have to implement something that sets checked_out to true when someone checks out the book.

edited: included that last else.

Comment: ah yes, already had a checked_out column in there, jsut didnt think to use it, so thats good, solves 1 issue, thanks very much, now i need to show a register button if the book is checked out (true) and the id is not mine (!=)  please see edit in question if you can help

Comment: thanks, so i dont need to declare anything, just else and then render whatever button i need to underneath?

Comment: got it, thanks you have been a great help, plus I need to read up some more on if/else statements i think after this..(and i was missing the = sign before render so it would have never outputted even if i had the statement correct